# JSmol - hide "JSmol" logo

Tags: rna-structure, 3d-structure

I'm using JSmol for my [SimRNAweb server](http://iimcb.genesilico.pl/SimRNAweb/jobs/260c8ff6-f24e-4eff-9760-1831407fc770/). I would like to hide "JSmol" logo from all small visualizations that I have there. I would like to just put information about JSmol under the panel in text.

[image: image of RNA with a JSmol logo at the bottom right]

Comment: I wanted to hide this JSmol little logo. Now I'm done :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I got an answer [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jsmol/discussion/general/thread/35965248/). Use:

`frank off`

to get:

[image]